# Defining command part by part 2

Tags: macros, grouping, definition

This question is an extension to [Defining command part by part](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/471399/defining-a-command-part-by-part/) thread. Let's say we have a command `\foo` with 1 argument. Can we produce a command `\setfoo{aaa}{<some stuff>}` which redefines `\foo` to: if an argument of `\foo` is equal to 'aaa', do 'some stuff'; otherwise do what \foo was supposed to do previously? I would also like to use \setfoo many times, so

```
\setfoo{a}{part1}
\setfoo{b}{part2}
\setfoo{c}{part3}
\foo{a}  \foo{b} \foo{c}
```

would produce

```
part1 part2 part3
```

Additionally, I want to be able to use `\setfoo` inside `enumerate`, and then use `\foo` inside or outside, so

```
\begin{enumerate}
\item First item. \setfoo{1}{part 1}
\setfoo{2}{part 2}
\item Second item.
\item Some text \setfoo{3}{part 3} Some text \foo{1}
\end{enumerate}
\foo{1} \foo{2} \foo{3}
```

would give

```
1. First item.
2. Second item.
3. Some text Some text part 1
part 1 part 2 part 3
```

I've tried egreg's solution from previous question, but all `\foo`s beyond `\end{enumerate}` were  undefined. MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand{\setfoo}[2]{%
  \expandafter\newcommand\csname tomasz@#1\endcsname{#2}%
}


\makeatletter
\newcommand{\foo}[1]{%
  \ifcsname tomasz@#1\endcsname
     \expandafter\@firstoftwo
  \else
     \expandafter\@secondoftwo
  \fi
  {\csname tomasz@#1\endcsname}%
  {BUMMER!}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}
\item First item. \setfoo{1}{part 1}
\setfoo{2}{part 2}
\item Second item.
\item Some text \setfoo{3}{part 3} Some text \foo{1}
\end{enumerate}
\foo{1} \foo{2} \foo{3}
\end{document}
```

This produces:

```
1. First item.
2. Second item.
3. Some text Some text part 1
BUMMER! BUMMER! BUMMER!
```

(BUMMER! is the output of `\foo{<x>}` when `\setfoo{<x>}{<something>}` was not used before.)

If it makes the problem easier, I could only use numbers as arguments of `\foo`, but I would appreciate general solution (when arguments of `\foo` are some strings of letters/numbers).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just make the definition global:

```latex
\newcommand{\setfoo}[2]{%
  \expandafter\gdef\csname tomasz@#1\endcsname{#2}%
}
```

`\newcommand` defines a macro in the current group (thus obviously in child groups). When this group is finished, the definition is lost: the macro definition is restored to the state it had before the group was started. In the case of a successful `\newcommand` call, the previous state is necessarily “undefined” or `\let`-equal to `\relax`, but if `\renewcommand` is used inside a group, the previous state that is restored when the group ends is the definition the command had before the group started. Example:

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\newcommand{\foo}{outside}

{ \renewcommand{\foo}{inside} \foo }

\foo

\end{document}
```

[image: Screenshot]

In contrast to `\newcommand` and friends (`\newcommand*`, `\renewcommand`, `\providecommand`, etc.), `\gdef` updates the meaning of the following token *globally:* the new definition transcends all groups.

Note that there are a few other differences between `\gdef` and `\newcommand`, apart from the syntax:

- A command defined with `\gdef` is not `\long`, unless the definition is like `\long\gdef\cmdname〈parameter text〉{〈replacement text〉}` (in the example below, you would need to replace `\gdef` with `\long\expandafter\gdef`). A `\long` macro accepts arguments containing `\par` tokens, whereas other macros throw an error when called with such arguments (the famous “runaway argument” error message). Not being `\long` is thus more restrictive, but this makes finding errors in one's (La)TeX code easier, assuming one has decided that `\par` tokens have nothing to do in an argument of the command being defined (which means the command should not be defined as `\long`; with the LaTeX2e kernel framework, it should be defined with `\newcommand*`).
- `\gdef` happily redefines the same command if asked to, whereas `\newcommand` would refuse to do so (it would throw an error). This behavior of `\gdef` may be a desirable feature in your case (?). If not, it's easy to add a check and error out in case the command is already defined.

Full code of your example with the `\gdef` fix:

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand{\setfoo}[2]{%
  \expandafter\gdef\csname tomasz@#1\endcsname{#2}%
}


\makeatletter
\newcommand{\foo}[1]{%
  \ifcsname tomasz@#1\endcsname
     \expandafter\@firstoftwo
  \else
     \expandafter\@secondoftwo
  \fi
  {\csname tomasz@#1\endcsname}%
  {BUMMER!}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}
\item First item. \setfoo{1}{part 1}
\setfoo{2}{part 2}
\item Second item.
\item Some text \setfoo{3}{part 3} Some text \foo{1}
\end{enumerate}
\foo{1} \foo{2} \foo{3}
\end{document}
```

[image: Screenshot]